# How to make clickable and open custom alert dialog in android listview?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build my own project list view where i use multiple image view with detail in single row but i can't be make it clickable and use my costume alert dialog layout how can i do it can any one help me. I try many of tutorial example of YouTube and also stack overflow site but those tutorial are not use for me and i'm stuck here i'm also beginner of android java programming.
This is my project github link can anyone help me to solve this project problem

[Link]https://github.com/rotaractnepalapp/SelectedApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/np/com/rotaractnepalapp/rotaract/ClubReview.java

Answer (score 0):

**Implement like this**

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog();
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager,"example dialog");
        }
    });
```

Comment: thx to reply brother @Aayush but it's doesn't work for me and sorry for late reply